# "NewRow" shortcut on OS X Mathematica 11 not working

Tags: keyboard, mac-os-x

The shortcut to add a row to a matrix ("ctrl"+"Return") on my OS X version 11.1.1.0, isn't working. Instead of inserting a new row it just inserts a new line into the cell. Has anyone else experienced this, and does anyone have a solution? I have looked through the "KeyEventTranslations.tr" file and everything is in order.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my mac, both `Ctrl-Enter` and `Ctrl-,` work for me in a matrix cell to add rows and columns, in the same version.

Comment: Could it be that some other application is hijacking the shortcut? You could try to check in another application whether that specific shortcut works

Comment: I am also having this problem, Mathematica 11.3 on a mac running OS X 10.13.6

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue. For some time I just ignored it because I've assumed that perhaps I've somehow broke it myself by writing custom stylesheets and packages or downloading something. Today though I got annoyed enough to dig deeper and I've verified it wasn't due to any autoloading package or stylesheet. It also didn't appear to be a conflict as I checked the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file (at least the user copy copy of it from `$UserBaseDirectory`, so I decided to switch the shortcut to `CTRL+M` and all the sudden I have now two working key shortcuts!
I'm not sure, but I think it points towards a conflict of redefinition of a sort.

Mathematica 11.3 on a mac running OS X 10.14.1

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and found that removing an add-on, mathStatica, fixed the problem (after a couple of restarts of Mathamatica). However, I suspect that this could be a bug in Mathematica, since clearing the `FrontEnd` entry in mathStatica's `PacletInfo.m` also fixed the problem, suggesting a startup issue.